# I'm trying to run tests with NUnit and MonoDevelop, I've got to be missing something obvious

Tags: nunit, monodevelop

I'm trying to get started with exercism.io and C#. I've installed the Exercism CLI without difficulty, and followed the Linux C# instructions (consisting of "Mono Develop is also available for Linux.") as far as that goes. I've also installed the NUnit plugin and I can see the panels come up when I go View -> Unit Testing.

What I can't do is find any way to add the test file. The Unit Tests panel is empty and I've tried every combination that I can think of as far as putting the file in different directories and adding it to the solution, etc. I can't figure out how to actually run the test.

This has to be something extraordinarily simple, but it just isn't coming to me. Found some mention of importing the file in a blog post, but I can't find an import option in any menu.

Mint 17.1 (KDE), Monodevelop 5.5, NUnit 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Just write test class, eg class with [TestFixture] attribute and which methods have [Test] attribute and signature of public void method(). Than run them with Ctrl+T. Should be simple as this. MonoDevelop with NUnit plugin parses tests automatically.

Comment: I should have said exersism.io in the description, to specify what I was doing just a little bit better. Exercism is a site that gives you a bunch of little programming exercises, and to test those exercises it gives you test files. Premade test files. So what I'm trying (and failing) to do is add those files to my project in a way which will allow me to run the tests. Doing it your way and copy / pasting the text from the given test file into the new test file does work. So I can get by with that, thanks. It's still a little clunky, but at least I can get it done now.

Comment: If file is regular .cs file, just add it to the project. Anyway I'll look into the site you've mentioned.